# Can we have Popup alert on Standard page before saving a record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to have a validation before saving a record on standard page layout of a custom object. before saving a record a popup message should be displayed. is this possible using any customization or visualforce and apex?

Comment: As far as I know, we can't show popup on standard page layout however you can write a validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done on a standard page. You will have to use customization. See the previously answered question this is a duplicate of.

On that note, please make sure you do a search before posting a new question, following the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Thanks!